# Gallery Permission in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, cross-platform

Currently I am facing Issue on React-native permission for Gallery access.

How to get Storage Permission for react-native-image-crop-picker because when i try to get storage permissions with react-native-permissions library it's "Block" in response so ho to get access photo and video from latest android version because in Android 11 below it's permission working proper so how to fix it please Help me out.

Comment: There is not such a thing as Gallery permission. And you can select pictures aa much as you want without needing permissions.

Comment: Without permission i can't get image so Always i need permission first and after i get image.